# php memory allocation problems

Tags: php, memory-management

I face an interesting behavior of my php on live server

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (MysqliDb.php on line 593 )
```

which points to `call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);`

Trying to incrase memory did not solved the issue. On my local machine I did not experienced this issue.

trying

> php -i | grep memory_limit
>
> ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

The query what I execute should not be a proble is a simple select with couple of records

```
$results = $this->db->get('feeds_categories');
```

Having altered my tables column from `longtext` to `varchar` seems to fix the issue but what is causing would be helpful to know.

Comment: What's the SQL query you are running? How big is your table?

Comment: There is really not much to say without more context. Probably you have quite a lot more data on your server. But this is just a wild guess.